# Remove set of values in an existing Set

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, I have the following [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)s:

```
var mySet = new Set(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
var valuesToRemove = new Set(["foo", "baz"]);
```

I need a function that removes a set of values:

```
removeAll(mySet, valuesToRemove);
// expected value of mySet: Set ["bar"]

// or a function that returns a new Set
var myNewSet = removeAll(mySet, valuesToRemove);
// expected value of myNewSet: Set ["bar"]
```

**Question:** Does any [ES6-modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)-compatible library exists that does the trick?

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/) has a [similar function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#pullAll) for [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s, but supporting JavaScript [builtin iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Builtin_iterables) is [tagged as `wontfix`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/737). And I prefer to avoid doing multiple Array↔Set/Set↔Array conversions.

Alternatively, I will write my own function.

Comment: The impressive design of the js stdlib. Even though it's a _relativly_ new functionality it lacks the most basic `Set` operations suggesting reinventing the wheel repeatedly.

Answer (score 8):

It is much easier to write your own function than use a library for a single lightweight functionality:

```js
var mySet = new Set(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
var valuesToRemove = new Set(["foo", "baz"]);

function removeAll(originalSet, toBeRemovedSet) {
  [...toBeRemovedSet].forEach(function(v) {
    originalSet.delete(v); 
  });
}

console.log([...mySet]);
removeAll(mySet, valuesToRemove);
console.log([...mySet]);
```

I have used ES6 syntax since you use ES6, according to your question.
You can this function in a static class like `SetUtility` for your convenience.

Comment: Really helpful answer. But I don't agree with you that it is easier. I think it is always easier to import a module than rewriting existing things. Besides, if I need other utility functions, I would just have to `import awesomeUtil from awesomeModule`. So I guess the answer to my question is: no, there is no ES6-module to do such a thing, right?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Set#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) directly with the set and delete then the value from the other set.

```js
var mySet = new Set(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
var valuesToRemove = new Set(["foo", "baz"]);

function removeAll(originalSet, toBeRemovedSet) {
    toBeRemovedSet.forEach(Set.prototype.delete, originalSet);
}

console.log([...mySet]);
removeAll(mySet, valuesToRemove);
console.log([...mySet]);
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! I have a bunch of solutions thanks to all of you. So I guess the answer to my question is: no, there is no ES6-module to do such a thing, right?

Comment: so basically yes, because of ` toBeRemovedSet.forEach((new Set).delete.bind(originalSet));` that works in a single line.

Comment: or take the prototype with the set as `thisArg`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for..of` loop `.delete()`

```
var removeAll = (keys, arr) => {for (prop of keys) arr.delete(prop); return arr};
removeAll(valuesToRemove, mySet); // `Set [ "bar" ]`
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! I have a bunch of solutions thanks to all of you. So I guess the answer to my question is: no, there is no ES6-module to do such a thing, right?

Comment: @MorganCourbet What do you mean by ES6-module?

Comment: Well, I'm quite a noob but instead of using `require` (that will evaluate the whole script, and allocate the necessary memory for every component in the script), you can, with ES6, use `import` & `export` to only pick the functions you want. That allows to include a big library without degrading the performance. But maybe I'm completely wrong :-D

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve?  [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) is not currently supported in browsers, see also [Babel transpiles 'import' to 'require', but 'require isn't useable in ecma5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166498/babel-transpiles-import-to-require-but-require-isnt-useable-in-ecma5) , [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: Yes I know but [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org) seems to transcript modules in a ES2015-compliant JavaScript.

Comment: @MorganCourbet How is this related to Question?

Comment: Originally, I was asking for an **existing** library/module/whatever-you-call-it to do the job **avoiding me to rewrite something that already exists**. That way, I would just `import`/`include` it in my project and use the wanted function. ES6-compliant was preferred as I don't want to degrade performances with a huge amount of functions I won't probably use (and I *do* know that I can transcript ES6 modules in ES5 with rollup.js or Babel.js). As I mentioned to the end of my question, the alternative would be to write my own function, which you did.

Comment: @MorganCourbet A library is not necessary to achieve expected result. Call `.delete()` for each value which you want to delete from `Set`, or create a function which does this. There are several Answers to your Question that perform this task.

Comment: I'm still learning JavaScript. That's why I find it easier to use an existing simple library and have a higher API level, rather than reinventing the wheel ;-) Thanks for your time.

Comment: No worries. Have you searched [`GitHub`](http://github) for what you are seeking? A possible starting point  [Harmony Collections Shim](https://github.com/Benvie/harmony-collections)

Comment: Yes, I have been looking during several hours for that. But there are tons of sites with a lot of information, and I must admit that it's quite complicated to have an up-to-date overview of the whole JavaScript standards, best practices, must-to-known frameworks or libraries. But that's part of the game!

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work try this,

```
Array.prototype.remByVal = function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < val.length; j++){
            if (this[i] === val[j]) {
                this.splice(i, 1);
                 i--;
            }
      }
    }
    return this;
}

var rooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var re= [1,4,6,7,9]
rooms = rooms.remByVal(re)

console.log(rooms)
```